# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln(1+u_n)$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We know that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty u_n^2<+\infty$ is convergent, then both $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+u_n)$ converge or diverge simultaneously. If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ converges and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty u^2_n=+\infty$, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+u_n)=-\infty$；If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+u_n)$ converges and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty u^2_n=+\infty$, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty u_n=+\infty$.

**My question is that:**  can we construct a sequence $\{u_n\}$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\ln(1+u_n)$ is convergent but $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ is divergent? In fact, it is suffices to construct $\{u_n\}$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n=+\infty,\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u^2_n}{2}=+\infty,\quad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty|u_n|^3<+\infty$$
and
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(u_n-\frac{u^2_n}{2}\right) \text{is convergent.}$$ Does such a sequence exist？

Comment: @BrianMoehring   here $u_n$ is alternated sequence. does it exists?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take $$
u_n  = \exp \left( {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{\sqrt n }}} \right) - 1.
$$
Then
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\log (1 + u_n )}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{\sqrt n }}} 
$$
converges, but
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {u_n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{\sqrt n }}}  + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}}  + \mathcal{O}(1)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{1 }}{{n^{3/2} }}} 
$$
diverges since the harmonic series diverges. (I used the fact that $\exp(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$ for small $x$.)

Comment: A great answer. By the way, $(e^x-1)^3=x^3+O(x^4)$, $e^x-1-\frac{1}{2}(e^x-1)^2=x-x^3/3+O(x^4)$ for small $x$. Hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n=+\infty,\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u^2_n}{2}=+\infty,\quad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty|u_n|^3<+\infty$ and
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(u_n-\frac{u^2_n}{2}\right)$ is convergent.